# How to install package ngram support for japanese with Mysql 5.6?

Tags: mysql, cjk, n-gram

I see document of mysql about ngram [enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html) support version 5.7 then it will be pre-installed but i use version 5.6, I want to install it manually, is it possible?
[image]

[image]

Comment: MySQL 5.6 has reached end of life and no longer gets security updates.  You should consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as possible.  The same will be true of 5.7 in a few months.